# How do I disable line centering in Intellij Idea Debugger?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

When debugging program in Idea (I'm using 14.1.5 Community Edition), it attempts to put the line I'm currently on close to the center of the screen. And it does so every single step. However, I find this default behavior very annoying, it looks like the code is jumping around.

I wonder if there a way to customize the debugger view in a way that the code would be fixed (as long as I'm not leaving one screen of code) and the current line highlighting would be moving around? (I didn't find it in the Debugger section of the settings.)

Many thanks.

Comment: Either I don't get your description or I've never encountered this behavior :) Could you share a screenshot llustrating this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You want to disable "Focus application on breakpoint" which is in the settings under `Build,Execution, Deployment > Debugger` - it's the first checkbox. It's help documentation reads:

> If this check box is selected, on hitting a breakpoint, IntelliJ IDEA will show the location of this breakpoint in the editor and will attempt to bring its frame to the front.

This should do the trick.